# Scheduled tasks concept

Tags: scheduled-tasks

I am new to the scheduling.

I created a website with two buttons. 
One for import data from text file to database.
Another one for joining data in excel and database.

Now what I want to do is
as every week, a new text file will be uploaded, I want to schedule so that my application import data to database every week.

How do I do it? I just need the concept.
What I think now is to schedule the server to make web request every week. Is this correct? Is there other better ways?

Comment: if your server is running linux, you can create cronjobs to perform scheduled tasks. No need to create a website.

Comment: Adding to @codefreak's comment - every usable OS have some kind of standard or even builtin task scheduler. It isn't job for web server to do that kind of things.

Comment: @keltar Thanks for the reply. What if I want user to define the scheduling time? Eg. User input is 1 day so the scheduled task will be run every day.

Comment: @Lin run scheduled task every so often (like 1 hour, 10 minutes, 1 minute - whatever better fits your needs), and check user settings within your task. It is likely to have more than one user anyway, right?